.NET Debugger Implementation
I am currently implementing a .NET debugger for my own language designed in ANTLR. I am using ICorDebug and related interfaces provided by .NET.
I have just finished implementing how to change values of basic types (bool, int , double) during debugging, but I cannot find out how to change a string value. It is different for reference types.
Obviously, reference value is represented by ICorDebugStringValue and by ICorReferenceValue. Also, it seems to me that I cannot change the existing string value, but I have to allocate a new string by ICorDebugEval.NewString() and then assign the new string to the ICorReferenceValue.
I tried to do so, but I always when I call ICorReferenceValue.SetValue(), I get exception that the value does not fall within a valid range.
Any idea how to change a string variable value during debugging?

Given that the question is not about ANTLR, I removed the antlr tag.
